# Sylius : customizing model fails for Taxon

Tags: sylius

I'm trying to customize the Taxon entity in Sylius, following this documentation : http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/model.html

In dev environment, no problem, everything works as planned.
But when I switch to the prod environment, I get the following :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] 
Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/webshop/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__SyliusComponentCoreModelTaxon.php'
```

It seems that the overridden class is still needed by someone, but I can't figure how to solve this. And I don't understand why the behaviour is different in dev and in prod...

Maybe I'm missing something ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to my own question : ...the problem was on my side... (as often :-) )

I have on this project overridden also the `Channel` entity, and have a `Channel.orm.yml` file which stores the relationship with the `Taxon` entity.

This file had to be modified so that the `targetEntity` is the **new** (i.e. overridden) entity, and not the one from the Sylius core.

```
(AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Channel.orm.yml)
...
targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Taxon
...
```

instead of

```
(AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Channel.orm.yml)
...
targetEntity: Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to run `php bin/console cache:clear -e prod`. It should to refresh var/cache directory with new configuration.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to describe what this does and why it might solve the problem.

Comment: This was obviously my first try :-) But even ca:cl fails on the prod environment